# Is it grammatically correct to use different languages in a sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

To give some examples:

> He has a certain *je ne sais quoi* about him. (French)
>
> I thought I'd go *au naturel* for our girls' night out. (French)
>
> That skirt with that blouse, I must say, what a fashion *faux pas*. (French)
>
> I don't like my meat *al dente*, I prefer it well-done. (Italian)
>
> Your *meshugge* cousin can be quite the *klutz*! (Yiddish)
>
> *Oy vey*, that *kamikaze klutz* almost gave me a heart-attack! (Yiddish, Japanese)

My question here is, is it grammatically correct to use more than one language in a sentence?

I know it is accepted to do so (appropriately). But! if anything this site in particular has taught me, just because it is accepted, it doesn't mean that it is correct.

I found these websites ([1](http://www.pfspublishing.com/workshop/2010/10/good-grammar-quickie-foreign-languages.html) and [2](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/italicizing-foreign-words/)) that say you should italicize them when you use them, but that doesn't answer my question if it is *grammatically correct*.

Reference(s) would be nice.

---

There is a comment regarding *au naturel* meaning **naked**, and while that is one definition, I'd like to point out that [it also means](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/au+naturel)

> in a natural state

Comment: @ΜετάEd: That ain't right.

Comment: @Mitch How so? And to what are you referring isn't right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this.  Use of foreign phrases is a matter of style and communication, not grammar.

Comment: @Pitarou would it be preferable that I just delete the question then?

Comment: @Souta In my opinion, yes it would be preferable.  But there appear to be some people who disagree with me.

Comment: @Pitarou Do you think you can explain to me why you don't agree that this question deals with grammar? (Or better yet, why you feel that this is *only* a matter of style and communication?)

Comment: With the possible exception of _meshugge_ and perhaps, _oy vey_, none of your italicised words are "foreign words". They are simply words of a foreign _origin_ that have been incorporated into English over time; you will find them listed in any modern English dictionary. The same is true of words which you have not italicised such as _blouse_ which is a [relatively recent French acquisition](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/blouse). If foreign words were considered ungrammatical, English would probably have a vocabulary of only ~5000 words instead of the ~750000 it does now.

Comment: In French, given the attitude of *l'Académie française* toward anglicisation, I suspect not.

Answer (score 9):

Mixing in foreign expressions has been a widespread practice in English for hundreds of years. It appears in literary, casual, and formal contexts.

This claim can be easily verified by consulting an English corpus. For example, you can use *Google Ngram Viewer* to search for any of the foreign phrases you used in your examples. One such search, [ [je ne sais quoi](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=je+ne+sais+quoi&year_start=1801&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) ], reveals that this phrase has been in continuous use in English publications for the past two centuries.

One critical lesson to take away from this site is that *usage determines what is
“correct”*. By definition, then, mixing in foreign expressions is correct because it is a common, well established usage.

About this claim that usage determines what is “correct” rather than the other way around, one professor of linguistics has the following to say in [an introductory course on the subject](http://www.linguistics.ucla.edu/people/schlenker/ling1-06-ln-1a.pdf)<sub>[PDF]</sub>:

> To know a language is to have in principle the ability to utter and understand infinitely many new sentences. How is this possible? The key is that speakers know (a finite number of) rules, which can be applied repeatedly to produce an infinite number of sentences. All spoken language is in this sense governed by *rules*; in this respect there is no difference between what is considered “good English” and what is considered “bad English” – they each follow rules, though they may be different ones. We will distinguish two uses of the notion of *rule*: for *prescriptive* vs. for *descriptive* purposes. *Prescriptive rules* are intended to teach people how they should speak or write according to some pre-determined (arbitrary) standard. They are of dubious origin, have no linguistic justification, and have no relevance for the linguist, who is solely interested in describing and understanding the rules that speakers do in fact follow (=*descriptive rules*).

Per @Nohat's suggestion, see also “[What is Grammar?](http://books.google.com/books?id=0BhzqFratIAC&lpg=PP1&ots=WQ54OBz3iy&dq=An%20Introduction%20to%20Language&pg=PA13#v=onepage&q=what%20is%20grammar&f=false)” in Chapter 1 (“What is Language?”) of Fromkin & Rodman’s *An Introduction to Language*.

Comment: Is there anywhere that says it is a precedent? And I have to slightly disagree with your point about _usage_ determining what is correct, being ain't isn't a "valid" word, but it is used often and used "correctly"

Comment: **Provided** the speaker is certain that the listener recognizes or understands the chunk that's in another language. If the listener doesn't do either of those things, it's exactly the same as making up phony language or babbling -- just noise, which doesn't have grammar. That said, there are thousands of words and phrases in thousands of languages that are used daily in speaking English. In various places, by various people, for various purposes.

Comment: If you mean ain't, it is not
incorrect. It is very unlikely
to be seen in formal
contexts, that is all. So it
could be said to be a social
faux pas to use it in a
formal situation, but not a
grammatical error.

Comment: @ΜετάEd If you can provide a reliable link to where it shows the precedents, that would be awesome. (Even with this new knowledge of that it is correct, I still can't find anything relating to this.)

Comment: Sometimes using different languages is simply _code switching_ (linguistic terminology). I do it all the time here in Taiwan. I sometimes have to use Chinese, Taiwanese, Japanese, and English in a single sentence to say what I want to say because I don't know how to say it all in a single language. In all of your examples, however, I'd say that the foreign words and phrases are actually English because they've been imported into the language and given English pronunciations, especially _kamikaze_, which is usually pronounced _kamakazi_ (kama rhymes with Obama and kazi with Swazi in Swaziland).

Comment: @BillFranke I understand that part, but that isn't what was asking.

Comment: You asked whether it was grammatically correct. Of course it is! It's not a question of grammar anyway. In your example sentences, the question is style: _Am I being pretentious and pompous if I use use these foreign words and phrases?_ In my example, it's a matter of necessity: I can't do it one language, so I use 4, as do lots of Taiwanese.

Comment: There's also the problem of the word _correct_. The obvious response is _Using what standard of correctness?_ Context determines that. As I often say, most of the questions asked here are about style choices, personal preferences, & sometimes disputed usages. Very few are really about _grammar_. Grammar is technical & very often only trivially interesting to anyone but linguists & grammarians. It's about the underlying rules of the language, the real rules that all native speakers know but can't necessarily articulate. Using a foreign language in an English sentence may break a social rule.

Comment: @souta, your presumption should be that if you see something done frequently by native speakers of a language, then it is "grammatically correct".

Comment: @BillFranke I understand where you're coming from now. My apologies. (In regards to necessity.) But I never intended for _pretentious and pompous_. I was just asking if something were correct, and then further asking ΜετάEd if he'd give a link for me to further understand this precedent. Again, I apologize.

Comment: @nohat If that were the case, then why isn't there anything saying that? And if there is something that says that, would you mind pointing me in the right direction (any references)? If these sentences are grammatically correct, foreign words included, then how is one to know if there is a grammar error made when there is no actual written precedent on the matter? (The matter being the foreign-English mix.)

Comment: @Souta, you might try the second section, "What is Grammar?" of chapter 1, "What Is Language?" of Fromkin & Rodman's *An Introduction to Language*.

Comment: @souta Here is [a link to nohat's citation](http://books.google.com/books?id=0BhzqFratIAC&lpg=PP1&ots=WQ54OBz3iy&dq=An%20Introduction%20to%20Language&pg=PA13#v=onepage&q=what%20is%20grammar&f=false).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not happy about the classification of all the OP's examples as 'not English' (by implication if not directly stated). Some, if not all, are regarded as **loan words** by various authorities. For instance, at http://www.palgrave.com/language/freeborn/site/pdfs/Wordbook_pdfs/20%20_Ch21.pdf , *al dente* and *kamikaze* are so regarded. I can't access the extensive Wikipedia lists, but I'm sure all the examples from French will be listed, and *klutz* and possibly *Oh vey!*

Admittedly, this is a grey area, with the AHDEL's rather imprecise definition being representative of current views on loan words:

A word adopted from another language and completely or partially naturalized, as *very* and *hors d'oeuvre*, both from French.

At http://grammarist.com/words/klutz/ is : Klutz, a noun, came to English from Yiddish in the late 20th century, and it has origins in the German klotz, which means a wooden block. In English, it means (1) a foolishly clumsy person, or (2) a stupid person, especially one who is socially inept. The word is more often used in the first sense.

At least one dictionary gives the English pronunciation *and* the Italian for *al dente*.

Perhaps partially naturalised expressions ('word' in 'loan word' really means lexeme - see Wikipedia) are partially acceptable. And quite English.

Comment: Yes, but if these 'loan words' that are accepted in English and have English translations, then would that mean it is more grammatically correct to use the English translation? I only say this, because for some of these accepted phrases, their translations don't always fit grammatically even if the original 'foreign' phrases and words do.

Comment: Or, if it doesn't always fit grammatically when translated to English, does that mean that the person misused the foreign phrase?